# How Three Phase transformer with single DC output works?

Tags: power-supply, current-transformer

How Three Phase transformer with single DC output works?
Can you give me some explanation?
and give some advice for DIY transformer with three phase input, single output?
It is better to use delta or star system for three phase DC power supply design, and why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120050/discussion-on-question-by-meow-how-three-phase-transformer-with-single-dc-output).

Comment: Seeking product recommendations is not allowed on EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor I not need product recommendations

Comment: You asked for a book recommendation. That's a product.

Comment: @Transistor Oh... ok... I wrong again... why this group is so conservative and legalistic ?

Comment: Because the site is for electronics design questions, not product recommendations. Please take the [Tour] to understand how it works.

Comment: @Transistor OK !

Comment: Seriously, you keep asking the same question over and over again. You're very clearly lacking basics of power electronics and transformers, and no amount of asking about complex switch mode supplies will change that. Stop calling DC supplies "transformer", for a start.

Comment: I not call DC supplies as "transformer", sorry for very bad languages

Comment: well, could you go ahead and fix the posts then? That would be a start. Then, explain exactly what you've researched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A block diagram for a switched-mode power supply (SMPS). Image source: [ATO](https://www.ato.com/12v-dc-4-2a-50w-switching-power-supply).*

- **I/P** can be single or three-phase.
- **Rectifier and filter** (1) will be single-phase bridge or three-phase bridge as required. The resultant DC voltage will be \$ V_{I/P}\sqrt 2\$.
- **Power switching** chops the DC at high frequency. This feeds AC to the ferrite transformer.
- **Rectifiers and filter** (2) generates the (usually) lower voltage DC required.
- The remainder of the circuit monitors the output voltage and feeds back to the control circuit to adjust the switching to maintain output voltage (or current if it's a CC power supply).
- Note the isolation provided by the transformer on the output and the opto-isolators on the control feedback circuit.

---

> ... give some advice for DIY transformer with three phase input, single output?

No. Buy one. You're not ready yet.

> It is better to use delta or star system for three phase DC power supply design, and why?

Delta is simpler.

Comment: Why there is two level rectifiers ?, and what's inside switching components ?, can you give me detailed schematics, thanks

Comment: What research have you done? Can I give you detailed schematics? No. You need to research this yourself. Again, this is an indication that you are far from qualified to build this.

Comment: I have done with single phase, but my circuit isn't efficient, only 39% efficiency, very very bad, do you think it's because my transformer is made from very bad wire ?, my transformer run very very hot, near 220 degree celcius, for 1kw input, output is only about 390 watt, very bad transformer :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is refering to an rectifier. If so, there's plenty of literature on power electronics explaining different topologies of three-phase rectifiers with single DC output.

For convential powerline transformers, there's a way to make three-to-single phase power systems using the "Scott-T" arrangement (I think there are other possibilities as well).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the minimal 3-Phase DC power supply. Delta configuration on the primary is the most common.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDVniS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>